# Upgraded from Rails 2.3.4 to 2.3.14 and now tests are failing (Shocking, I know)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

The problem seems to be with all tests that do POST, PUT, DELETE requests. It seems that csrf token is not being attached with those requests. Thus I get redirected to /login. It's perfectly fine with GET requests of course.

It's worth to mention that actual browser interactions are fine. So it works in dev, but not in test environment.

Anybody else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So the issue was with `protect_from_forgery`. For some unknown to me reason `before_filter :login_required` was triggering too early. I don't know the specifics or how to 'properly' fix this. But doing this allows me to run my test finally:

```
protect_from_forgery unless Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the csrf security vulnerabilities that were fixed.  If you haven't already added csrf_meta_tags and updated your jquery-ujs file you may need to do that as well for the upgrade.  This may not be the case if it works in development mode though.  Heres a more detailed blog post about the subject.  http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-csrf-vulnerability

Comment: I added csrf_meta_tags and stuff. Everything works fine in development. I can submit forms with no issues. Tests, however, fail. So it seems that some internals are not sending over the token somehow. And that really shouldn't have anything to do with what happens in the views or js.